# Fox hung meaning in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

— I'm reading a book by Richard Hughes, The Fox in the Attic. 
In the first page, chapter one "Polly and Rachel" there is a phrase that I didn't get it.

"and here in a sodden tangle of brambles the scent of a **fox hung**, too heavy today to rise or dissipate."

— What does that mean?
A smell of a fox that has been hung?

— I found in the dictionary that hung can be used as: (be hung with) be adorned with. *the walls of her hall were hung with examples of her work*

— In that way I might understand that a scent of a fox was in the air, not a scent of a **fox hung**.

Could you clarify it to me? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scent (of the fox) *hung* - stayed around - in the air.

Comment: So the subject of *hung* is *scent*, not *fox*.